# how to remove SIGTSTP error from code below?

Tags: c++, runtime

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int T;
    cin>>T;

    while(T--){

        int a,result=1;

        cin>>a;

        for ( int i= 2 ; i < a ; ++ i ){
            if(a%i==0){ result=0; break; }
        }

        if(result) cout<<"Yes"<<"\n";
        else cout<<"No"<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

hello this is the problem

tells whether number is prime or not 
if yes then output is "yes" else "no"

Comment: what is the input you give?

Comment: The code looks fine. May be you are solving a problem online and in the runtime,  either memory or time has exceeded beyond some limit and it would have stopped your program abruptly. Try to optimize your program (there is lot of scope for it)

Comment: Input:
5
23
13
20
1000
99991

Comment: ohk @Wander3r yes you are right.